# Media Query with grid-template-areas doesn't work

Tags: css, angular, sass

I need write a simple media query that transform my `grid-template-columns` from 4 columns to 3 when my screen width is smaller than 992px. I'm developing with Angular5 and, on my SCSS style file I wrote this media query but it doesn't works.
Furthermore, I tried to use this code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas#Redefining_the_grid_using_media_queries, but still not work..

```
.header-context {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto auto 40px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "back title    title   ."
    ".    subtitle actions .";
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: white;

  .back-action {
    grid-area: back;
    align-self: start;
    }
  }

  .title-container {
    grid-area: title;
    align-self: start;
  }

  .subtitle-container {
    grid-area: subtitle;
    align-self: start;
  }

  .actions {
    grid-area: actions;
    align-self: end;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 .header-context {
    grid-template-columns: 32px auto auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "back title    title  "
      ".    subtitle actions";

    .back-action {
      grid-area: back;
    }

    .title-container {
      grid-area: title;
    }

    .subtitle-container {
      grid-area: subtitle;
    }

    .actions {
      grid-area: actions;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A demo would be ideal!